# Can the tag of MPI_Send() be a long int?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I am working on my project which uses `cpp` and `openmpi`. Inside my program, there are many "compute units", I call them **elements**. For each element, I generate a unique `unsigned long int` to identify it, I call this integer **key**.

The problem is that I now need some elements to communicate with each other among processors, namely using `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`. Since each element knows who it should send messages to and receive messages from, i.e., it knows the key of the target element that they should send to or receive from, it would be intuitive to use the key as the `tag` in `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`. However, I see the `tag` in the [man page](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man3/MPI_Send.3.php)
of openmpi is an `int`. So it is a 4 bytes integer? Is it possible for me to use an `unsigned long int` as the tag? Thank you very much!

Comment: The short answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately, tags cannot be `long int`s. The C bindings define the tag as `int`, but the set of actually allowed values is even smaller and is also implementation-dependent. For one, tags must be positive. Then there is an upper bound (UB) imposed by the MPI implementation that is available by querying `MPI_COMM_WORLD` for the `MPI_TAG_UB` attribute:

```
int flag;
int *tag_ub;

MPI_Comm_get_attr(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_TAG_UB, &tag_ub, &flag);
if (flag)
  cout << "Max allowed tag value is " << *tag_ub << endl;
else
  cout << "No idea what the max allowed tag value is" << endl;
```

Not only may the value vary between the different MPI implementations, but it may also vary given the same implementation based on the communication transport(s) selected by the job (I've seen this happen with certain MPI implementations). The standard only guarantees you that the value of the tag UB will not be less than 32767.

Your best and most portable option is to make the element ID part of the actual message data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I should consider other option of tags.